# selecting multiple groups

Tags: selection-tools, groups

I am trying to select two groups at a time. I tryed shift + G and select a group, than select another object from another group, and hit shift + G again, but the previously selected group was deselected, how can I make to select two or more groups?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

- Clear selection with <kbd>a</kbd>
- All click can be done in the outliner window
- In the outliner window show groups.
- Click on first group
- Shift click on the second group.